# Retrieve value passed to a called back function in a mathjax-node Node.js example

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, mathjax

I am trying to use the example

```
// a simple TeX-input example
var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node/lib/mj-single.js");
mjAPI.config({
  MathJax: {
    // traditional MathJax configuration
  }
});
mjAPI.start();

var yourMath = 'E = mc^2';

mjAPI.typeset({
  math: yourMath,
  format: "TeX", // "inline-TeX", "MathML"
  mml:true, //  svg:true,
}, function (data) {
  if (!data.errors) {console.log(data.mml)}
});
```

from [this page](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node).

From what I see the method `typeset` passes the output I need to a function input in its second argument.

I don't want to print the output `data.mml`. I need to assign it to an external variable for further processing.

**Question:** How can I assign `data.mml` to a variable that is outside the scope of the anonymous function passed to `typeset`?

The anonymous function is not able to modify variables from the global scope (outside `typeset`) because that is not the immediate scope from the the anonymous function is called.

Comment: Can you re-open this question so I can ask some details? I didn't understand how to answer this using the linked question.

Comment: OK, I think I am starting to understand. It is the first time I see asynchronous code.