# The flow of information in asyncronous calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjax

This question is a followup to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581677/retrieve-value-passed-to-a-called-back-function-in-a-mathjax-node-node-js-exampl).

[Should I explicitly reproduce the content here?]

Mind the fact that this is the firs time I learned about asynchronous code flow.

I read also about 'promises' in JavaScript.

I think I understood, at least in part, the idea in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/5487882). In very short terms, I need to put what I need to do with `data.mml` in the callback function passed to `typeset`.

Now, I am a bit stuck in how to organize the flow. This is what I need to do overall (which I didn't get to add in my previous question):

I have a string, say

```
var input = 'First $a^2=b$ second $a+b+c=d$ last';
```

I will split it

```
var splitted = input.split('$');
```

So we should get

```
splitted = ['First ', 'a^2=b', ' second ', 'a+b+c=d', ' last'];
```

And then odd elements of `splitted` are the ones that need to be transformed into MathML by `typeset`.

Say that we are about to process the first odd element `a^2=b`. At some point in time `typeset` will produce the corresponding MathML. Lets call it `data`. With the idea I got from the linked answer I would need to put what I need to do with `data` inside the call back function. What I need to do is to insert it as the **second element** of `splitted`. There is some extra processing before inserting but let us skip that for the sake of clarity. So, just the insertion part. When processing `a+b+c=d` it would be the **fourth element** of splitted.

My problem is that it seems that **second element** and **fourth element** are information that is external to `typeset`. So, how would the called-back function know that the `data` that was entered this time is the one corresponding to `a^2=b` and not to `a+b+c=d`.

Ah! Maybe it is relevant the fact that I don't have control over the signature of the callback function that should be passed to `typeset`. From what I know the function has a single input which is `data` containing the MathML.

Comment: Possibly what you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044807/passing-scope-to-callback-function-binding

Comment: @phenxd Let me see. Sounds similar.

Comment: @phenxd Yes, this solved the problem, part of it. By defining the anonymous callback function in the same scope as an extra variable, I can access the latter inside the callback function, and effectively retrieve an output out of the callback function. It is not the end of my problem, as I still need to figure out how to loop asyncronously through the elements of `splitted`. Right now the transformation is working and it is getting out. But the loop is not assigning them until the end of the loop. But that is a different question. Thanks.